# UICollectionView showing vertically even when scroll direction is set to horizontal?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I am trying to paint `UIScrollView` list horizontally using this code but not working expected?

```
    let nib = UINib(nibName: cellIdentifier, bundle: nil)
    collectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout(withParentView: view)

    self.collectionView.delegate = self
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self
```

Flow Layout method

```
// #PRAGMA mark - UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

func layout(withParentView parentView: UIView) -> UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 160, height: 65)
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    return layout
}
```

and here is the delegate and dataSource methods

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! RowCollectionViewCell

    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 248/255, green: 248/255, blue: 248/255, alpha: 1)
    }else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    }

    cell.label.text = "Field\(indexPath.row)"

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    return CGSize(width: 160, height: 65)
}
```

When I run it shows this (Vertical list of items). Is there anything I have missed out. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flow layout uses a **line-based** layout. What this means for you is that if you set the *scroll direction* to *horizontal*, then the cells will be laid out in a line form *top to bottom* until no more space is available and then move on to the next line.

You can verify this easily by changing the number of cell to something higher. (like 10?)

---

I recommend you watch this [video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/225/) to get a better understanding of how `UICollectionView` works.

Comment: I have changed a number of cells to 10 and field8, field9 goes to next column and now it's scroll horizontally. But How can I achieve a single cell will go to the next column?

Comment: @Vishal16 Try reducing the collection view size or increasing the item size.